# Draw line from armature animation

Tags: armature

Is there a way for me to draw a line from an armature. Currently I have a basic solar system made, circular orbits around the sun, heliocentric with orbital rings showing there paths. Easy, now I took that same animation and had the camera map to the earth, no orbitals paths, the geocentric model. I want to draw the orbitals in relation to the earth.

So I have armatures anchored on the earth stretching to the other planets, is there a way to get the armature at the other planets to draw a line, or path, using that animation.

So I can draw the lines kinda like this:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [BTrace Blender Addon](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Curve/Btrace) for that purpose.
I don't know if it can track armatures, it might only work on meshes, not sure but you can probably easily add a mesh to your armature to accomplish the desired effect

Comment: Works perfectly!