# Solid representing the swept volume of another animated solid

Tags: animation, boolean-modifier

This is to create a twist lock mechanism when 3D printed.

I have a cuboid rotating around its z-axis. I want to remove part of an existing solid to allow the cuboid to rotate for 60 degrees. To do this, I need to create a solid which represents the entire swept volume of the rotating cuboid and then I can apply a boolean difference modification. How can I create this swept volume solid?

Initial Position:
[image]

Ending position:
[image]

**UPDATED QUESTION:**
I have successfully created the swept volume solid.

Now, for some reason, the boolean difference modification is not working. I managed to somehow get the same effect using a boolean intersect modification (???) with one of the joints, but I can't get either to work for the other joints.

[Here is the .blend file](https://uniofnottm-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/eeymg2_nottingham_ac_uk/ETMWve-oyxZIh5hFMBqA_qIBdYKAkaBxaKynYfiB702CAQ?e=idH0l2)

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48866/draw-line-from-armature-animation https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52830/is-it-possible-to-create-a-path-from-an-existing-object-animation